# persisting of multiple dependant objects using hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am using multiple tables A and B. I need to persist dependant objects A as well as Object B at a time on giving saveOrUpdate. Is there anything like I can pass multiple dependant objects to saveOrUpdate function in hibernate?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand what you mean by dependent objects. You may take a look at the [cascade configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone) which is available on all references.

Comment: Steinegger  
the thing is that using one object itself can i persist the other object as well like I have objects A and B. B has foreign key relation with A. So If I pass object B can I persist object A as well. Hope you understood

Comment: Yes, I think what you are looking for is cascade. Set cascade="all" in the mapping file.